# My website doesn't like one line of my code but it works on JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chunk of code that works on `JSfiddle` but not on my website.

So I viewed the frame source code of my example in `Jsfiddle` and the page source of my website. The javascript and html is nearly identical and I tested any differences and they weren't the problem.

I have entered my code for my website line by line and this is the line that's not working. I have other jquery that works fine.

```
lotslist.push(row.find("td").eq(0).html());
```

Any idea what the problem with this one line could be? Here is the entire chunk.

```
var lotslist = [];
$(function() {

    var rows = $('tr').not(':first');

    rows.on('click', function(e) {

        var row = $(this);

        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.shiftKey) {
            row.addClass('highlight');
            lotslist.push(row.find("td").eq(0).html());

        } else {
            rows.removeClass('highlight');
            row.addClass('highlight');
            lotslist = [];
            lotslist.push(row.find("td").eq(0).html());
        }

        var unique = [];
        $.each(lotslist, function(i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, unique) === -1) unique.push(el);
        });
        $(document.body).append(unique);
    });

    $(document).bind('selectstart dragstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

});
```

It should be noted if I remove anything with the lotslist array from the program the rest of the JS still works. For example, when I click on a row in the table it properly highlights it.

Comment: Go into Chrome Devtools and look at the error console.  How do you even know it is that line?

Comment: Have you wrapped the JS in [`$(document).ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)? JS fiddle does that inherently.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well as wrapping it in CDATA[] like jsfiddle does.

Comment: How is it not working? Is it erroring out (there should be an error message on the console if so). If it isn't erroring out what is getting pushed onto the array? Have you logged each part of `row.find("td").eq(0).html()` to make sure each part is returning what you think it is supposed to be? Give the link for your jsfiddle

Comment: I just get a 500 internal server error which is what I get whenever my website has a bug, thats why I debug chunks on jsfiddle. I'm sure this is a terrible way of doing things but I have no CS background, I'm just doing this as a side project at work.

I can link the jsfiddle in a few minutes but it has a lot of work sensitive stuff I need to edit out.

And yes I've logged each part of the row.find("td)... and it is giving me what I expect.

Comment: If you don't have this line of code, you don't get page 500?
Error 500 is supposed to happen on server render time, this error you are pointing on the other hand is a runtime error

Comment: @iagowp you're right, it was a problem with my python program that's creating the web page ): Sorry to waste time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it and it's embarrassing. The find("td") quotations were messing with the string the javascript was in. Since my python program is printing the javascript to my webpage. It was so small I couldn't notice the color change in my editor. Sorry for the silly mistake.